# place div tags on tags on top of each other using css

Tags: css

I have following code which consists of two tags. `.nav` and `.page` with I want to place `.nav` at the top with `position: fixed` and `.page` below `.nav`. How can I do this without using `margin` property?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBxNr/)

And here is code

```
 <div class="nav">this is navigation</div>
 <div class="page">this is page</div>
```

CSS

```
 .nav {
display: block;
position: fixed;
border: 1px solid red;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
}

.page {
border: 1px solid green;
height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Why not using `margin`?

Comment: want it to be more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use the relative positioning? This positions the "page" element to show 50px of where it should be displayed if this hadn't been set.
Additional benefit all absolute positioned elements within the "page" element will reference the "left:0px;top:0px" as the top left corner of the page element instead of the browser viewport.

see the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/HBxNr/1/

```
position:relative;
top:50px;
```